# Getting direction between coordinates without using Google direction web service

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, driving-directions, google-directions-api

I know it is possible to get direction between coordinates using Google's direction web service. But is there any other way to get equally accurate route?

I found few questions on SO those use `http://maps.google.com/` to get direction. But then also found few answers on other questions which state that it is no longer supported.

I am confused as this is the first time I am dealing with Google maps for android.

Is there any built in android sdk method to get direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send an intent to the google maps app and have the app do all the work for you but its not documented and probably never will be.

to do that you can either give it a lattitue/longitude like this

```
Intent NavIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +latitude +","+longitude));
startActivity(NavIntent);
```

or using the same intent but with an address and see if maps can resolve the address. (I dont have an example with an address).

Other than using google directions API or other 3rd party direction web services there really is no other way to get directions in your app unless you look at `Open Street Maps` where you calculate the directions yourself using way points but that is quite involved

Comment: I also want to display few markers on map with custom titles. And I want to display direction between 5 pairs of coordinates at the same time. I also need to show some custom layout on mapView. Is it possible to do all this using google maps app the way you said?

Comment: no it is not, the only thing this intent will do is give you the route. you are going to have to use google's directions API or another 3rd party directions web service to do what you want

Comment: It is ok if I can just get direction between coordinates. I am fine to display route mapView using android maps api v2. But is it equally accurate direction if I get from google maps app? I wonder because otherwise everyone would use that approach only, instead of using google direction web service which limits the usage to some queries per day.

Comment: to get the specific directions like what street to turn and such then your only option is using a mapping web service to get them to you

Comment: I don't need the textual representation of route such as when to turn and where to turn. Just visual representation on mapView. I think you meant the same but want to clarify.

Comment: oh ok so then yeah the intent I have will show the route on the google maps app but that takes the user away from your app. If you want to display it in your app then you need to use one of those web services to get them. Or use Open Street Maps and manually figure out the route yourself (Basically writing your own mapping with offline maps)

Answer (score 0):

Firing an intent to the google maps app is what I've choosen to use in my application, the philosophy here is that Android apps should exploit and complement each other functionnlities

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(getDirectionUrl(srcLat, srcLng, dstLat, dstLng)));
if (isGoogleMapsInstalled(this)) {
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
}
startActivity(i);
```

method to build the directions URL:

```
public static String getDirectionUrl (double srcLat, double srcLng, double dstLat, double dstLng) {
    //return google map url with directions 
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=")
    .append(srcLat)
    .append(",")
    .append(srcLng)
    .append("&daddr=")
    .append(dstLat)
    .append(",")
    .append(dstLng);
    return urlString.toString();          
}
```

Method to test if Maps is installed:

```
public static boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled(Context c)  {
        try
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            ApplicationInfo info = c.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
            return true;
        } 
        catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The downside is that Google may change the URL structure.